# python docopt: "expected string or buffer"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using docopt module to handle python script options :

```
from docopt import docopt
"""Usage:
  ./convert [ -h | -i | -t | -c ]

Options:
  -h          Show this help
  -i          Convert image to vertical scroll box
  -t          Convert text to vertical scroll box
  -c          Convert command list to html
"""

def main(docopt_args):
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__, version='v0.1')
    main(args)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ajn/Converter-yaml-to-html-blocks/convert.py", line 66, in
>
> args = docopt(**doc**, version='v0.1')   File   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 558, in
> docopt
> DocoptExit.usage = printable_usage(doc)   File   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 466, in
> printable_usage
> usage_split = re.split(r'([Uu][Ss][Aa][Gg][Ee]:)', doc)   File   "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 196, in split
> return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit) TypeError:
> expected string or buffer

Any hint?

Comment: I suspect that the `__doc__`  you're passing is `None`, which is neither a string nor a buffer. (Remember: "Explicit is better than implicit".)

Comment: what was the solution for this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Move the doc string to the start of the file (before the import line)

Comment: I didnt understand this...can anyone reply to this ?

Comment: the docstring is the string literal after the import. I added a new answer explaining it a bit

Answer (score 1):

To anyone confused, when using `docopt` you should write a docstring before the `from docopt import docopt`. The options for the arguments are generated by parsing that string automatically. In this question the docstring is:

```
"""Usage:
  ./convert [ -h | -i | -t | -c ]

Options:
  -h          Show this help
  -i          Convert image to vertical scroll box
  -t          Convert text to vertical scroll box
  -c          Convert command list to html
"""
```

and should have been placed before the import.

See more examples at the README of the project [here](http://docopt.org/)